# sbackup fails to connect via ssh when run via sudo

Tags: ssh, backup

I prefer to run sbackup via sudo to be able to backup other things than my normal user has access to. But sbackup fails to connect to the specified host via ssh when it is run via sudo. It says

> Unable to mount host

Still I have no problem to ssh into the specified host with my normal user. Is there any way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you run sbackup via sudo you need to add the specified host to the local root account. To do this run invoke ssh via sudo to login with your normal user, i.e. if your normal user is nn:

```
sudo ssh -l nn <address to specified host>
```

You will then see something like

```
The authenticity of host [...] can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is [...]
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

Choose yes here and you are done (you do not actually have to log in).